# Isn't this const auto& redundant?

Tags: c++, constants

I found this code in one of Stroustrup's books:

```
void print_book(const vector<Entry>& book)
{
     for (const auto& x : book) // for "auto" see §1.5
           cout << x << '\n';
}
```

But the `const` seems redundant because `x` will be deduced to be a `const_iterator` since `book` is `const` in the parameter. Is `const auto` really better?

Comment: The first thing I think of when I see `for (auto& x : something)` is that it's modifying the elements. It's nice to have my expectations line up with reality when reading code.

Comment: I would resort to habit building argument: It spends you less mental power to write good code when you have a habit that is good and general.

Comment: @chris There's the opposite problem though. Somebody may think `x` is modifiable if they don't realize that `book` is `const`.

Comment: Its more robust in case the function changes to receive a non-const vector. Then the loop is still doing the right thing for its own purposes.

Comment: *"x will be deduced to be a `const_iterator`"*, No `x` will be deduced as `const Entry&`.

Answer (score 70):

In my opinion, it looks *explicit* which is why it is *better*. So if I mean `const`, then I'd prefer to write it explicitly. It enhances *local reasoning* and thus helps others to understand the code comparatively easily — other programmers dont have to look at the *declaration* of `book` and infer that `x` is `const` as well.

Comment: Plus, including the `const` in the `for` indicates that the loop isn't going to be modifying `x`, even if `book` happened to be non-`const`.

Answer (score 34):

Code isn't just for the compiler to read — it's also for humans to read. Conciseness is only good when it does not come at the expense of readability.

In the given code, deducing constness is immediate. With your proposed change, deducing constness would require the reader to accurately remember or review the definition of `book`.

If the reader is intended to be aware of constness, brevity would be counterproductive here.

Answer (score 14):

It's much clearer seeing the keyword `const`. You immediately recognize that it's not going to be modified, if the `const` keyword wasn't there we wouldn't know unless we looked up to the function signature.

Using the `const` keyword explicitly is much better for the readers of the code.

---

Moreover, when you read the code below you expect that `x` is modifiable

```
for (auto& x : book) { ... }
```

And then when you try to modify `x` you'll find that it results in an error because `book` is `const`. 
This is not clear code in my opinion. It's better to state in code that `x` is **not** going to be modified so that others that read the code will have their *expectations* right.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to take a different angle here. `const` and `const_iterator` mean completely different things.

`const` applied to an iterator means you cannot modify the iterator itself, but you can modify the element it points to, much like a pointer declared like `int* const`. `const_iterator` means you cannot modify the element it points to, but you can still modify the iterator itself (ie. you can increment and decrement it) much like a pointer declared like `const int*`.

```
std::vector<int> container = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
const std::vector<int> const_container = {6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
auto it1 = container.begin();
const auto it2 = container.begin();
auto it3 = const_container.begin();
const auto it4 = const_container.begin();

*it1 = 10; //legal
*it2 = 11; //legal
*it3 = 12; //illegal, won't compile
*it4 = 13; //illegal, won't compile

it1++; //legal
it2++; //illegal, won't compile
it3++; //legal
it4++; //illegal, won't compile
```

As you can see, the ability to modify the element the iterator points to depends only on whether it's an `iterator` or `const_iterator`, and the ability to modify the iterator itself depends only on whether the variable declaration for the iterator has a `const` qualifier.

Edit: I just realized this is a range for and therefore there is no iterators at play here at all (at least not explicitly). `x` is not an iterator and is actually a direct reference to an element of the container. But you have the right idea, it will be deduced to have the `const` qualifier regardless of whether one is explicitly written.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to offer a counter-point. In Herb Sutter's talk at CppCon 2014 [**"Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style"**](https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=2089) (timestamp 34:50), he shows this example:

```
void f( const vector<int>& v) {
  vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();       // error
  vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); // ok + extra thinking
  auto i = v.begin();                        // ok default
```

He argues that `auto` will just work even if you change the parameter of the function, since it correctly deduces `const` or `non-const`. Further on slide 36, he states "You should know whether your variable is const/volatile or not!" as reasoning for why "auto&&" is bad for local variables.

Essentially it boils down to a matter of opinion. Some think that being explicit is good for readability or maintainability, but the opposite could be argued: being redundant shows a lack of understanding (either of C++ rules or what your code is actually doing<sup>1</sup>) and could harm readability and maintainability. Do whatever you think is best.

<sup>1</sup>: This is a rather contrived example, but C++'s rules of thumbs don't really work in the general case and are hard to remember. For example, Herb Sutter recommends you have constructor parameters pass by value contrary to regular function overloads. This is one of those situations where `const` everywhere could bite you in the foot, depending on whether or not you agree with Herb.

Comment: I think you're quoting it out of context. In this code you posted,if you add `const` there and make it look like  `auto const i = v.begin();`, then here explicit `const` seems to be incorrect pattern, because you wont be able to `++i` for example. Adding `const` to iterator declaration doesn't make the referent `const`, it makes the iterator itself `const`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning `const` early and often tells the reader of the code more about what is going on *without* the reader having to look further away in the code.

Now, given your code, I'd write it as:

```
void print_book(const std::vector<Entry>& book)
{
  for (auto&& x : book)
     std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

or even:

```
void print_book(std::experimental::array_view<const Entity> book)
{
  for (auto&& x : book)
     std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

but only because the code is so short would I omit the redundant `const`.

(The `array_view` version removes the useless dependency on the argument being a `vector` -- `vector<?> const&` is usually over specifying your interface, as a `vector<?> const&` provides nothing useful that an `array_view<?>` does not provide, yet can force copies from initializer lists or from raw C arrays or the like.)

There is no reason to use `const auto&` over `auto&` or `auto&&` as far as the compiler is concerned, as all 3 (in this context) are deduced to be the same type.  The only reason to use one or the other is to talk to *other programmers*.

In my case, I use `auto&&` by default (it says I am iterating, and don't really care what I'm iterating over).

`auto&` if I know I need to modify, and `auto const&` if I want to stress I am not modifying.

Answer (score 1):

this specific example is quite simple, because input array is declared as `const`. In general, using `const` in ranged-based for can be useful for both developer (he will get compiler error if he tries to modify container) and for compiler (explicit `const` sometimes help it to optimize code)

Comment: 1) "***he will get compiler error if he tries to modify container***". The developer will get the error even if he does not mention it explicitly but deduced to be `const`. 2) "***explicit const sometimes help it to optimize code***"..I doubt that seriously, because the compiler *knows* it anyway; explicit mention of `const` does not help the compiler any further.

Comment: @Nawaz, 1) `std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4}; for (auto &i : v) i++;` is completely legitimate. As I said, in general. 2) assuming two external functions: one takes `const int &` and second `int &`. Thus, `int i = 5; func(i);` can be optimized to passing `5` directly in first case, but not in second.

Comment: Andrei, please dont speak out of context. This topic is about "const" which seems redundant to the OP, which means if you dont write it, the compiler will deduce `auto` to be const-qualified type. So the question, in this context, is: Is writing `auto const &` is redundant? or it helps in some sense?

Comment: @AndreiR.: _"but not in second"_ Nonsense